# Como usar um nome com colchete (parênteses retos) num selector de jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual é a melhor maneira de chamar um elemento que tem parênteses retos no nome, usando jQuery?.

**HTML**

```html
<div name="name[1]"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```javascript
$('div[name=name[1]]'); //errado?
$('div[name="name[1]"]'); //correto?
$('div[name="name\\[1\\]"]'); //correto?
$('div[name=name\\[1\\]]'); //correto?
```

Comment: Está divertido aprender o português aqui :) Colchete é parente recto.

Comment: Agora fiquei na dúvida, parente recto não está correto (ou correcto :) ) em Portugal?

Comment: @bigown, acho que depois do acordo ortográfico do ano passado recto passou a reto... mas como estou a viver na suécia à 5 anos ainda falo o português "antigo" :)

Comment: "parêntesis recto"

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo então deve ser com "i" em parêntes**i**s? e deve ser "reto" ou "recto"?

Comment: @Sergio "parêntesis" e "parêntese" são sinónimos. Eu uso a grafia "recto" porque não escrevo conforme o desacordo ortográfico. Já agora, é "há" (do verbo "haver" e não "à", que é uma contracção de uma preposição com um artigo definido).

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo ok :) um edit é bem-vindo!

Comment: @Sergio Não necessariamente. Conforme o AO90 está correcto.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O primeiro exemplo `$('div[name=name[1]]');` está incorrecto, e dá o erro
`unrecognized expression: div[name=name[1]]`.

As outras opções estão correctas, se bem que por razões ligeiramente diferentes.

**Explicação:**

- `$('div[name="name[1]"]')` **é ok** de usar porque o jQuery trata`name[1]` como uma string, uma vez que está dentro de aspas, e não como um selector CSS/jQuery, e assim não precisa de ser blindado com o escape `\\`.
- `$('div[name="name\\[1\\]"]')`, **funciona, mas não precisa de `\\`**. O jQuery lê o o selector `name\\[1\\]` como uma string pois está dentro de aspas, e no javascript a barra invertida faz com que a segunda barra seja ignorada`\` resultando em `\[`, que por sua vêz é o mesmo que `[`. Assim este exemplo tem barras invertidas sem necessidade.
- `$('div[name=name\\[1\\]]')` **é ok** e os parentes rectos internos `[]` têm de ser blindados com barras invertidas desse modo para não serem confundidos com selectores CSS/jQuery.

**Da documentação do jQuery:**

> Para se usar qualquer um dos seguintes meta-caracteres `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ `` como parte de um nome, têm de ser blindado com duas barras invertidas, barras à esquerda: \\.

### **Exemplo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/W37a9/)**

---

**Mais leitura (em Inglês):**

- *MDN - [Escaping characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Escaping_characters)*
- *jQuery - [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)*
- *W3.org* - [Characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)