# Selecionar elemento "select" com jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, html-select

Eu criei na minha página um `select multiple` e preciso pegar seus valores no PHP em forma de vetor, logo adicionei `[]` no final do nome. Exemplo:

```
<select id="selecionados[]" name="selecionados[]" size="20" multiple ">
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Até ai tudo bem, porém preciso antes de enviar o formulário pegar o elemento `selecionados[]` com Jquery.
Porém nem com `$('#selecionados')` nem `$('#selecionados[]')` funcionam.

Como consigo pegar esse elemento por jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `id` do `select` não precisa conter o `[]`, altere para `id="selecionados"`

```
<select id="selecionados" name="selecionados[]" size="20" multiple >
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

E no jQuery, exemplo:

```
$('#selecionados').on('change', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Exemplo: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/2897v/)**

Answer (score 3):

Eu acho que a pergunta aqui é como usar `[]` dentro do seletor jQuery...

Já dei uma [resposta sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211/129), e no seu caso pode usar assim:

Usando `\\` ou no caso de usar o `name`, com aspas dentro. Exemplo:

```
var selectID = $('#selecionados\\[\\]');
console.log(selectID); // selecionando por ID

var selectNome = $('select[name=selecionados\\[\\]]');
console.log(selectID); // selecionando por nome/name
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/VCZ3d/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

```
$("select[id^=selecionados]");
```

Isso vai trazer o elemento que você descreveu.