# Como chamar função de partial após adicionada via append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, tenho uma `partial view`, que eu rendenizo com o seguinte código:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#DIV").append(data);
            }
        });
```

E dentro dessa página, eu chamo uma função

```
<script> 
   Funcao(selectorId);
</script>
```

Eu preciso que essa função seja chamada dentro da `partial view,` após ser carregada com append

Pois o parametro (selectorId) da função é recebido único, então toda vez que eu chamar para rendenizar em  `$("#DIV").append(data);` o parametro selectorId será diferente...

Como posso fazer isso?

---

Meu elemento é montado assim no código ASP.NET:

```
<input id="Contatos[@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()].Nome" name="Contatos[@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()].Nome" type="text" value="0">
```

Exemplo de ID resultante:

```
Contatos[8902dbfd-e856-48c6-8f17-d0548b2dea62].Nome
```

Comment: Se entendi corretamente, o que você tem deveria funcionar. Dá algum erro no console?

Comment: não @bfavaretto , entretanto, parece-me que o elemento quando eu chamo a minha função, ainda não foi rendenizado, pois o mesmo não encontra alguns data atributos...

Comment: Quando você diz "dentro dessa página" se refere à partial? O script está no fim da partial?

Comment: Sim, ele deve ser chamado após o append, mas o script está dentro da partial, é que eu gero o atributo "ID" que é passado para a função, internamente na Partial, então cada vez que faço uma chamada dessa partial o atributo Id será um diferente...

Comment: Você não pode retornar esse valor na chamada ajax e executar a função de lá com esse ID?

Comment: @bfavaretto vendo suas respostas, vi que trabalha ou trabalhou com c#, bom, a ideia, é que eu gero os meus elementos os elementos assim: `<input id="Contatos[@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()].Nome" name="Contatos[@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()].Nome" type="text" value="0">` Então faço a chamada da função passando o parametro Id, e lá na função uso $("#" + parametro") para pegar o elemento

Comment: @AndréRibeiro não sei dizer, já que eu gero o atributto Id lá na partial view, como mostrei no comentário acima

Comment: @Rod Acho que seu código JS está ok. O problema pode ser que seu seletor contém um `.`, que o jQ vai interpretar como seletor de classe. Tente escapar o ponto com `\.` ao passar pra função.

Comment: @bfavaretto pode ser...meu Id está sendo gerado assim: `Contatos[8902dbfd-e856-48c6-8f17-d0548b2dea62].Nome` Mas ao passar assim: `Contatos[8902dbfd-e856-48c6-8f17-d0548b2dea62]\\.Nome` também não obtive sucesso

Comment: Os colchetes também podem ser problema, têm outro sentido em seletores.

Comment: @bfavaretto exatamente :D funcionou...se quiser informar como resposta, eu adiciono demais detalhes na pergunta

Comment: Vou tentar postar mais tarde, se ninguém fizer isso antes :) Aproveito pra registrar o link de uma pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211/como-usar-um-nome-com-colchete-par%C3%AAnteses-retos-num-selector-de-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse seu tipo de ID tem vários caracteres que não são interpretados literalmente quando usados em um seletor. Por exemplo, um seletor assim:

```
#Contatos[8902dbfd-e856-48c6-8f17-d0548b2dea62].Nome
```

Vai procurar um elemento cujo ID seja `Contatos`, que tenha um atributo chamado `8902dbfd-e856-48c6-8f17-d0548b2dea62` e que tenha a classe `Nome`. Por exemplo:

```
<div id="Contatos" class="Nome" 8902dbfd-e856-48c6-8f17-d0548b2dea62></div>
```

Mas não é isso que você quer... Então é necessário escapar os caracteres que estão causando a confusão, `[`, `]` e `.`. O jQuery precisa receber isto:

```
#Contatos\[8902dbfd-e856-48c6-8f17-d0548b2dea62\]\.Nome
```

Portanto a string precisa ser montada assim:

```
"#Contatos\\[8902dbfd-e856-48c6-8f17-d0548b2dea62\\]\\.Nome"
```

**Referência**: [Como usar um nome com colchete (parênteses retos) num selector de jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211/como-usar-um-nome-com-colchete-par%C3%AAnteses-retos-num-selector-de-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Crie a função na partial sem chamá-la e chame depois do append.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#DIV").append(data);
            funcaoDentroDaPartial();
        }
```